# Ajax reques new data not all data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, razor

Is there a better way to request new data from the server instead of requesting all the data again plus the new record? for example: if I have a website like twitter and I write a tweet I would like the server to show me the new tweet not every tweet plus the new one.

**Here is my jquery code:**

```
$(".submitt").click(function () {
    txt = $(".texto").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/comment.cshtml",
        global: true,
        data: { text: txt },
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#com1").html(result);
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("There was a problem submiting your comment, please try again later");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**And here is my C# Razor code (.cshtml)**

```
@{
 var db = Database.Open("PhotoGallery");
  var texto = Request.Form["text"];
 if(texto != null){
        db.Execute("INSERT INTO Photos (UploadDate, UserId, CommentText) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)", DateTime.Now, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, texto);
  }else{
      return;
  }
 var photos = "SELECT TOP 19 * FROM Photos INNER JOIN UserProfiles AS r ON Photos.UserId = r.UserId INNER JOIN Friends AS t ON Photos.UserId = t.Q WHERE t.P = @0 ORDER BY Photos.Id DESC";

}
@foreach (var photo in db.Query(photos, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId))
        {
 <div>etc etc etc...</div>
}
```

Comment: This is usually done with a timestamp sent by the ajax of when the last data was "fresh" and then you do a `SELECT whatever WHERE last_changed > timestamp_from_ajax`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a infinite loop client-side with JS, then run a delay in, and when the delay (ex : 1 min) is passed, you call your Ajax query to execute a query which return and append only informations which has been inserted between the current time and current time - 1 minute.